# echo in function not appending to div [PHP]

Tags: php, html

I made a container into which I want to echo divs. This works fine if I do it with simple PHP code, but if I use a function to echo it, it isn´t in the container div. Please help me so I can echo the div into the container (via function).
Result: https://gyazo.com/745b3d304c20ab58c00a37f7ac936383
For some Reason it´s at the code´s top: https://gyazo.com/30e3d6fcc8aca7567caf5c21c8ba4cc7

```
<div class="container">

     <div class="lek"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list" id="symbol"></span>
          <div class="name"><p class="nametxt">English</p>
               <div class="cards"><p>10</p></div>
          </div>
     </div>
<?php 
    echo "<div class='lek'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list' id='symbol'></span>
          <div class='name'><p class='nametxt'>Test1</p>
          <div class='cards'><p>10</p></div>
          </div>";

function RefreshLektionen($array) {
     $y = 0;
     while(calcLek() > $y) {  
          createLektion($y);
          $y++;                    
     }   
}  

function createLektion($val) {
     echo "<div class='lek'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list' id='symbol'></span>
           <div class='name'><p class='nametxt'>".$val."</p>
           <div class='cards'><p>10</p></div>
           </div>"; 

}

echo "<div class='lek'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list' id='symbol'></span>
      <div class='name'><p class='nametxt'>Test2</p>
      <div class='cards'><p>10</p></div>
      </div>";

?>
```

Comment: Where did you call `RefreshLektionen()` function? Also, what does `calcLek()` function do?

Comment: You only need to call the function `RefreshLektionen()`

Comment: there's no call to RefreshLektionen()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should try this by return string instead of echo.

```
 function createLektion($val) {
           $string='';
           $string.= "<div class='lek'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-list' id='symbol'></span>";
           $string.= "<div class='name'><p class='nametxt'>".$val."</p>";
           $string.= "<div class='cards'><p>10</p></div>";
           $string.= "</div>"; 
           return $string;
        }
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

It will work but the function RefreshLektionen needs to be called, put the line RefreshLektionen($array); after the function declaration.